# Unknown crash report android

Tags: java, android, crash-reports, android-logcat, backtrace

I have released an app on Google play store and started rolling out updates, the latest one seemed to worked fine until I received this crash report from a user
can anyone help me figure out what it is exactly, what caused it and the possible ways of fixing it ?

**Device info:** Asus ZenFone 2 (ZE500CL) (ASUS_Z00D), 2048MB RAM, Android 5.0

```
Backtrace:
native: pc 0000000000090df6  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+22)
native: pc 0000000000038d13  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+163)
native: pc 000000000003a5f5  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+37)
native: pc 0000000000032855  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+85)
native: pc 00000000000104da  /system/vendor/lib/libsrv_um.so.1.12.3197934 (PVRSRVDebugAssertFail+58)
native: pc 0000000000006e82  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so.1.12.3197934
native: pc 000000000001b576  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so.1.12.3197934
native: pc 000000000001b6d1  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so.1.12.3197934
native: pc 0000000000009d72  /system/vendor/lib/libIMGegl.so.1.12.3197934
native: pc 000000000000fcea  /system/vendor/lib/libIMGegl.so.1.12.3197934 (IMGeglMakeCurrent+1514)
native: pc 00000000000015a3  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so.1.12.3197934 (eglMakeCurrent+51)
native: pc 000000000001133f  /system/lib/libEGL.so (android::egl_display_t::makeCurrent(android::egl_context_t*, android::egl_context_t*, void*, void*, void*, void*, void*, void*)+303)
native: pc 0000000000014e3b  /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglMakeCurrent+635)
native: pc 0000000000087fce  /system/lib/libhwui.so
native: pc 000000000008247f  /system/lib/libhwui.so
native: pc 0000000000088b24  /system/lib/libhwui.so
native: pc 0000000000088623  /system/lib/libhwui.so
native: pc 000000000008b55a  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+154)
native: pc 0000000000016ece  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+398)
native: pc 0000000000071d23  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+99)
native: pc 00000000000165cb  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+123)
native: pc 0000000000037cdb  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+59)
native: pc 0000000000032fba  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+26)
native: pc 0000000000011df6  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
```

Comment: Seeing the *exact* same error on an Asus ZenFone 5 running Android 5.0. Did you ever find a resolution, or just decide to ignore it?

Comment: @TylerV it is answered below

Comment: Yes, but the answer is to either 1) ignore it, or 2) get the same device and test it to figure out what's causing it. I was wondering if you took path 2 and found anything more.

Comment: as far as I can remember I ignored it, and I also checked other forums and dev communities and they all agree on ignoring those types of errors because mainly they cause no harm @TylerV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a native crash meaning a bug that was in the user's device itself not a bug in your code. I don't know what's the bug though, but that's what it means. I, personally, sometimes ignore these types of crashes if they don't occur too much. But if it occurs again and again, then you will have to see what new code you added in your new version and try to find out what was causing this issue by removing parts of your new code part by part and test it on the same device until you find it out. Unfortunately, you may not have the same device, but that's the way to fix this if it's really needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use CrashLet

> Implementation

**In your build.gradle**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**In your application's build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
        implementation 'com.github.Collabalist:CrashLet:1.5'
}
```

**Usage:**

```
public class SamApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        CrashLet.with(this)
            .addRecipient("abc@gmail.com")
            .addRecipient("xyz@gmail.com")
            .showStackTrace(true)
            .init();
    }
}
```

Comment: What benefits over Firebase Crashlytics or even Google Play Console?

Comment: Firebase Crashlytics,Google Play console or Fabric Crashlytics are more better than this...but only when your app is live cause this library is only helpful when your app is in dev-environment.

I just developed this cause some of android devices won't able to print Logs even when they are connected, and this is helpful even when we give app to clients for testing purpose.